# Stumbleupon badge xhtml validation errors

Tags: javascript, html, validation

The stumbleupon's badge is breaking giving xhtml validation error. Is there any kind of way to make it validate using javascript or something else?

The su gives following line to display the badge:

```
<script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=5"></script>
```

And i get following two warnings:

```
line 5 column 1 - Warning: <html> proprietary attribute "xmlns:fb"
line 40 column 2 - Warning: <span> ID "__su_server_time__" uses XML ID syntax
```

Comment: What is the validation error?

Comment: @Jason McCreary, sorry, I edited the posted.

Comment: Warnings are not errors. What are you using to validate? Is this a live site? Just provide the link so we can check ourselves.

Comment: no its not live, if you paste this code in any html, you will get the output.

Answer (score 1):

Note that *warnings* are not *errors*.

The code you provided validates on an otherwise valid page except for XHTML Strict doctypes using the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check)

If that is your doctype, you need to add the `type` attribute as instructed:

```
<script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=5" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You need to be mindful of the doctype as these are what's used for validation. So *paste this code in any html* will not result validation errors.